# Is it ok to utilize repeated Thread.sleep() for creating delay to receive an SMS

Tags: android, multithreading, sms

An `Android` application sends `SMS` to a predefined phone number and then verifies if the sent `SMS` is received in the `SMS` inbox or not to make sure the `Simcard` has not been changed

If the sent `SMS` is received, the `Simcard` is the same and application goes on

If the sent `SMS` is not received, the `Simcard` is not the same and application exhibits a message indicating that the `Simcard` is changed and the predefined `Simcard` should be replaced

The problem is it takes some time to receive the sent `SMS`
The application can utilize `Thread.sleep(1000)` and every **1 second** verifies the `SMS inbox` and if the message is received, then escapes

If the message has not yet been received, the application utilizes another `Thread.sleep(1000)` and the same procedure till **10 seconds**
After **10 seconds** the application makes decision that the Simcard is changed

Is it ok to utilize this procedure or there is a better solution ?

Comment: You might want to include some actual code.  The answer is, maybe, but it depends on what you are actually doing.

Comment: this flow is flawed, what if the sim card is correct but the SMS takes 11 seconds to arrive?

Comment: Threads use memory.  I don't know android, but if there already is some timer thread that you can use to accomplish the same task, then using it will reduce the memory footprint of your app.

Comment: @Tim Castelijns, it may take even 1 hour or more to receive SMS but most of them are received in less than 10s, so a logical dead time is needed anyway

Answer (score 0):

It’s not recommended to put code logic using thread.sleep, try implement some other idea that may includes events

Comment: how do you suppose he can do that, if the very event he would be listening for might never arrive